# Scroll By Id pós acesso - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

A situação é a seguinte, eu tenho um link que ao acessar deveria ir a um ponto especifico de uma pagina especifica, mas estou tendo problema com isso, pois ao acessar essa mesma pagina através de qualquer outro link ela NÃO deve escrolar até o ponto:
essa é a função onClick:

```
<script>
    function acessar()
    {
        var link = "<?php echo base_url()?>/Site";
        var newWindow = window.open(link, _self);
        newWindow.paramTeste = "passoApasso";//id da Section
    }
</script>
```

esse é o código executado na pagina pós acesso onLoad(que no caso, só rola para o ponto se tiver parâmetro):

```
<script>
        function RolarPara(){
            var elemento = document.getElementById(window.paramTeste);
            elemento.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'});
        }
    </script>
```

mas, só funciona quando eu uso o `window.open(link, _blank)` e eu precisava que fosse `_self`.
O que posso fazer?